# Podfile Syntax reference “Platform” in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

Now i am working on Xcode 7.2 with iOS version 7.2 .My application uses  one library implemented by cocoapod file.I need to update this podfile using “pod update” command in terminal.My client wants to this application deployment target to 7.0. When i am going to update podfile i am confused about this line of code like platform :ios, "5.1.1" .How to write this line pod file like  platform :ios, “7.0” or platform :ios, “9.2” ?